# Why is there no space left in my /boot?

Tags: boot, updates, disk-usage

My OS is Ubuntu 15.10. More than **200M** disk space was to set to /boot when I installed this OS in my laptop. But now I can not upgrade any softwares ,kernel included.

The terminal told me that no space is left in directory /boot. When checking the properties of file /boot, it displays that only around  **60M** are used but with no space left, as shown in the picture[60.7M used, 0 free space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRpoa.png). When I check this issue with the tool *Disks*, it shows as this [space usage shown by Disks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRs2P.png). When I check in terminal with the command *df -h*, it shows that no space is available.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I solved my problem as posted below.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I figure out why.

There is a invisible file *.Trash-0*  in /boot. All the kernels that have been downloaded are in this invisible file, but I don't know why this happens. The invisible file occupies all the rest space except for that for the visible files in /boot.
200M space is available after I remove the files in /boot/.Trash-0. I can now update the kernel.

I should have tried more before posting this question.